# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object (stored procedure) 'xxxxxxx', database 'zzzzzzz', schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a pipeline built to push the CSV to the SQL Server. On running the pipeline, I encounter this error on the Execute db transform step in the pipeline. I have verified using the code that I have all the required permissions and also I am using same accounts in the pipeline and the SQL Server

I checked all the permissions granted to my account using

```
SELECT *
FROM fn_my_permissions('[dbo].[SPROC name]', 'OBJECT') 
ORDER BY subentity_name, permission_name ;
```

Comment: Could you tell which pipeline you are using?

Comment: I am using Azure Data Factory

Comment: Do you execute across the database?

Answer (score 0):

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object (stored procedure) 'xxxxxxx', database 'zzzzzzz', schema 'dbo'

To resolve the above error you need to give `public` access to the **object** like below.

```sql
USE [YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE];
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.[YOUR OBJECT NAME HERE] TO PUBLIC
```

or you need to create a role and grant permission to that role like below.

```sql
CREATE ROLE db_user;

GRANT EXECUTE TO db_user;
```

Below is the sample `CSV` file stored in Azure storage.

```
Id,FirstName,Age
1,Balaji,25
2,Pavan,24
3,Sai,26
4,Venkatesh,29
5,Siri,32
```

Below is the Stored procedure, created to store csv data into the Azure SQL table.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertData (@source StudType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FirstTable
    SELECT * FROM @source
END
```

After executing the pipeline in ADF data has been copied successfully from Azure storage to Azure SQL DB as shown below.
[image]

Refer this link for [GRANT object permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN).